# Storing temporary chunk uploaded files in Redis

Tags: asp.net, redis

We have chunked file uploads where an uploaded file is split by the client into multiple 1MB chunks and each chunk is uploaded separately and appended to a temp file on the server.

With our multiple frontends we're looking at getting rid of sticky sessions and in this case different chunks can end up on different frontends.

We're looking at files up to 200MB in size.

Does it makes sense to store the chunks in Redis *appending each new chunk to an existing cache entry* shared among the frontends?

Does Redis support appending to an existing cache entry?
Will it be any good in terms of performance considering the size of the data compared to using a NAS file share to store the temp file and append to it?

Answer (score 4):

The maximum length of a Redis value is 512 MB, so you're good. Note [Redis strings](https://redis.io/topics/data-types) are binary-safe.

Appending each new chunk to an existing cache entry is possible, see [`APPEND`](https://redis.io/commands/append) command. This makes sense if you are sure your chunks will arrive in order. Otherwise, you may want to use one key (or an entry in a list, hash, set, or sorted set) per chunk.

Performance-wise, it should be much better from the client perspective because Redis is in-memory, NAS is disk storage. It also allows you to receive chunks in a different order (if you don't use append) and to decouple client upload from your persistence and post-processing logic.

You want to make sure you'll support your peak upload scenarios. Make sure you look at [expiration](https://redis.io/commands/expire), and [eviction policy](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache).

Comment: @axk did you end-up using this solution? Did it work out well, any pitfalls? I'm looking at doing something similar.